# Compute detailed Age of a Person in Groovy?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I want to compute the age of a person in the following way:

Let x be the age of a person.

- if x < 1 week return age in days
- if 1 week < x < 1 month return age in weeks
- if 1 month < x < 1 year return age in months
- if 1 year < x return age in years and months

**How can I compute that kind of age function?**

Comment: What should the length of one month be?  ie:  how do you want to say `1 month < x < 1 year`?  Also, what are you going to do with leap years?  Also, if I was born on the 31st January, what would you show my age as on the `28th February`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with dates I suggest you use Joda-Time (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html). Then you are able to do this:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.Period

String getAge(birthday) {
    def period = new Period(birthday, new DateTime())

    int years = period.getYears()
    int months = period.getMonths()
    int weeks = period.getWeeks()
    int days = period.getDays()

    String age

    if (years > 0) {
        age = "${years} year(s) and ${months} month(s)"
    } else if (months > 0) {
        age = "${months} month(s)"
    } else if (weeks > 0) {
        age = "${weeks} week(s)"
    } else {
        age = "${days} day(s)"
    }

    return age
}
```

For more information take a look at the documentation of DateTime (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) and Period (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html).

Since you tagged your question with Grails I'm guessing you are needing this functionality for a Grails project. If so you can use the Joda-Time plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time) for adding required dependencies.

Comment: This is close, but what I need is the following. When age is 5 weeks than it should output 1 month and 1 week. The same for weeks. 8 days should output 1 week and 1 day. 14 months should output 1 year and 2 months.

Comment: @Confile Say I was born on the 1st October.  On the 31st October, I would be 4 weeks and 2 days old, what should it print then?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you restate your conditions using the smallest feasile time unit, in your case days, and use that to build your if statement

```
// x is age in days
if (x < 7) {
    return x;
}
if (x < 31) {
    return x/7;
}
```

You also need to decide how many days you consider a month and a year to have, as both vary.